# checking audio file exists with javascrip only

Tags: javascript, file, audio, mp3, exists

I have a webpage which need to play a mp3 file (if exists)
But I can only javascript only...

I tried the different method, but I still cannot check the file exists or not..
it sometimes works in IE,
but not work in chrome

---

Updated on 20200731

I've updated my code

now I have updated my code with 2 functions
executeIfFileExist  <-- check the file exists
playme  <-- play the mp3, this is fine and I can play the music now.

the check file exists function still not working.
even my file exists in server, the player still not show.

anyone can help me.
Thanks a lot.

```html
<script>
function executeIfFileExist(src, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", src, true); 
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
      callback();
    }
  };
  xhr.open('HEAD', src);
}

function playme(mp3file)    {
    //$("#playAudio").attr('src',mp3file).autoplay;
    $('#playAudio').show();
    $("#playAudio").attr('src',mp3file).play;
}
function showTips(url,event){
    $('#tipsimg').attr('src', url);
    // start
    $('#playAudio').hide();
    mp3file = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".mp3";
    mp3file = '01.mp3';
    alert(mp3file);
    // $("#playAudio").attr('src',mp3file).play();
    // playme(mp3file);
    executeIfFileExist(mp3file,playme);
    // end
    $('.tips').show();      

    //event.preventDefault();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    showTips('01.png',null);
})
</script>

<div class="tips">
  <img src="" data="image1" id="tipsimg" />
  <br />
  <audio id="playAudio" controls autoplay>
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to add this?
`sound.onload = (event) => {
  ...
}`

Comment: added but not working..  :(

Answer (score 2):

You can have a function to check whether the file exists or not, try this out!

```js
function executeIfFileExist(src, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
      callback();
    }
  };
  xhr.open('HEAD', src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found answer and tried myself, at least it works (hide the audio tag if not found)
but it still show a js error if the file not exists

wish its helpful

```js
function executeIfFileExist(src, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     callback(src);
    }
  };
  xhr.open("GET", src, true); 
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';  // add these line will loop until the file is ready
  xhr.send();  // add these line will loop until the file is ready
}

function playme(mp3file)    {
    $('#playAudio').hide();
    $('#playAudio').show();
    $("#playAudio").attr('src',mp3file).play;
}
```